# Full-Text Search by last name, first name and second name

Tags: sql-server, view, full-text-search

Hello I use **SQL Server** and I want to make a Full-Text Search  in folllow table

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    firstName varchar(MAX) NOT NULL CHECK (firstName != ''),
    secondName varchar(MAX) NULL CHECK (secondName != ''),
    lastName varchar(MAX) NOT NULL CHECK (lastName != ''),
    birthDate datetime2 NOT NULL CHECK (birthDate >= '1.01.1990'),
    recordBookNumber int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (recordBookNumber > 0),
    enrollmentDate datetime2 NOT NULL CHECK (enrollmentDate >= '1.01.1990'),
    groupId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Groups](id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

So I've created view StudentsSearchView, Clustered Index, Fulltext catalog and Fulltext Index

Fulltext Index is here:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON
    dbo.StudentsSearchView (
        firstName LANGUAGE 1033,
        secondName LANGUAGE 1033,
        lastName LANGUAGE 1033
    )
KEY INDEX IDX_SEARCH ON ftCatalog
WITH (
    CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, 
    STOPLIST = SYSTEM
)
```

So I have a textbox, where I input string like 'John Peter Smith' and I want to get all 
matches, but I can't to fint out what query I need to use for it. I try this

```
SELECT * FROM
    dbo.StudentsSearchView
WHERE CONTAINS (
    *, '"LastName*" & "FirstName*" & "SecondName*"'
)
```

But nothing found, although I have in table this row.

**P.S.** LastName, FirstName and SecondName will insert programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. My mistake is View. It was

```
CREATE VIEW
    dbo.StudentsSearchView WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    id, firstName, secondName, lastName
FROM
    dbo.Students
GO
```

But It needs to be like this:

```
CREATE VIEW
    dbo.StudentsSearchView (id, Fio) WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    id, firstName + ' ' + ISNULL(secondName, '') + ' ' + lastName
FROM
    dbo.Students
GO
```

So, now this Select query works

```
SELECT * FROM
    dbo.StudentsSearchView
WHERE CONTAINS (
    *, '"LastName*" & "FirstName*" & "SecondName*"'
)
```